Trying to use regex as path for my nginx location
main page: (should be / or anything other  than phpmyadmin and other folder....)
location ~ (?!phpmyadmin|smf|zDev|DiscordCommunicator|wordpress|Monitor|announcements) {
#...
}

fastcgi pages (should start with / and phpmyadmin or any of the other folders):
location ~ (?:phpmyadmin|smf|zDev|DiscordCommunicator|wordpress|Monitor|announcements)\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.php {
#...
}

special page (should be any js file or html or....):
location = (?:phpmyadmin|smf|zDev|DiscordCommunicator|wordpress|Monitor|announcements)\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.(?:js|mhtml|htm?l|css|png|gif|jpg:jpeg:xml|ico|map|webp|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|mp3|m4a|aac|ogg|midi|wav|mp4|mov|webm|mpe?g|avi|ogv|flv|wmv))$ {
#...
}

main fastcgi page (should be / with phpmyadmin or any other folder only):
location = (?:phpmyadmin|smf|zDev|DiscordCommunicator|wordpress|Monitor|announcements)(?:\/$|$) {
#...
}

i am trying to manage paths' regex on NGINX's location blocks...any page or directory always  points  to the main page without respect of any other location block...(e.g phpmyadmin/index.php is ignored  and / location  block is used instead)
these regular expressions  works like charm on regex sites like regexr but doesn't work with NGINX idk why

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I am trying to create some routes for my ExpressJS and FastCGI using my NGINX... the first route is the main page & the second route is the common FastCGI route and the third is a special page dedicated for routing static files like jpg and js files and the fourth page is the main FastCGI page... when i try to open any page from the mentioned routes it gets redirected silently to the main page of ExpressJS and it seems like a problem with regex of location blocks

What you are trying looks similar to $ find /{var,lib,bin,usr} -maxdepth 0 which would yeild a list of matching folders e.g. /var, /lib, /bin, /usr for my example. Is such a result really suitable in your situation?

yes... you understood what i am trying to do
